# Displaying Json data in ajax call

Tags: c, asp.net-mvc

my problem is after ajax call i return a collection of date and time after converting it to json this is what i get "/Date(1377532800000)/" does anyone know how to convert it back to original format? im using MVC c#

Comment: the format should be like this 9/3/2013 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

That is the time elapsed in seconds after a particular date. You can format it anyway you want. Below is a sample format. Just parse the int the way you want it to be and convert it to string if that is how you want it to be represented.

```
(new Date(parseInt(HDate.substr(6))), 'dddd, MMMM dd yyyy');
```